# elements in general product

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ be a group with subgroup $H=\langle h \rangle \times C$, where $h$ is infinite order and $C$ is finite central in $A$.
Suppose there exists $M \lhd_{f} A$ such that $M \cap \langle h \rangle=\langle h^{r} \rangle$ where $r$ is any positive integer.
It is clear that $\langle h \rangle \cap C=1$ and $h, h^{2}, \ldots, h^{r-1} \notin M$.

Question 1: are $h, h^{2}, \ldots, h^{r-1} \notin MC$? if not, is there any condition(s) can be added to make it true?

Question 2: if there's an additional condition, $c, c^{2}, \ldots, c^{r-1} \notin M$, in what condition we can have $hc, h^{2}c^{2}, \ldots, h^{r-1}c^{r-1} \notin M$ or $hc, h^{2}c^{2}, \ldots, h^{r-1}c^{r-1} \notin MC$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: As to me, the correct usage of \langle...\rangle counts as an effort.

Comment: By "finite central" you mean that $\;|C|<\infty\;,\;\;C\le Z(A)\;$ , right? And what does $\;M\lhd_f A\;$ mean? Perhaps that $\;M\;$ is invariant under some automorphism $\;f\;$ of $\;A\;$ ...?